# ArrayList link for an element and get IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my code briefly:

```
public class FabianFerenc extends FogolyBase{

    ArrayList<Boolean> ellenfelValaszai = new ArrayList<Boolean>();


    private void deleteList(){
        for(int i=0;i<ellenfelValaszai.size();i++){
            ellenfelValaszai.remove(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean masikEllenVall(int iFordulo) {

        if(this.ellenfelValaszai.size()>0){
            System.out.println(this.ellenfelValaszai.get(iFordulo));
        }

        if(this.ellenfelValaszai.size()>999){deleteList();}
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void masikMitMondott(int iFordulo, boolean bMasikValasza) {
        this.ellenfelValaszai.add(bMasikValasza);
    }
}
```

And when I want to write all content from the "ellenfelValaszai" list in the "masikEllenVall" method, and I all time get this error msg:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:638)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:414)
    at Foglyok.FabianFerenc.masikEllenVall(FabianFerenc.java:51)
```

The iFordulo variable a counter which count from 0 to 999.

Comment: The stack trace is pretty self-explanative. Unlike your code.

Comment: If i add 2 to "iFordulo" place I get error too.

Comment: I would recommend verifying items are being removed from the `List`. You might be better off looping backwards, or better yet simply just calling `clear()`

Comment: @PumpkinSeed, sure you should check is there item at this place, but you only checks is an array an empty or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
 @Override
     public boolean masikEllenVall(int iFordulo) {

    if(this.ellenfelValaszai.size() > iFordulo){ //if iFordulo always >= 0 it's sufficient check to be sure array isn't empty
        System.out.println(this.ellenfelValaszai.get(iFordulo));
    }

    if(this.ellenfelValaszai.size()>999){deleteList();}
    return true;
}
```

also read other answers, especially regarding how to clear your array.

Comment: This is good, now I need to find out why have my list only one element.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1` is telling you that the size of the array is 1. Indexing of the elements in Java arrays starts with 0, so the single element can be accessed via `ellenfelValaszai.get(0);` but you are trying to get that element by using index =1. Hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error that you have enclosed states that you are trying to access element with index 1 while there is only 1 element in list (so the biggest index you can use in the list is 0). Also, I recommend you to replace your deleteList() method with simple `ellenfelValaszai.clear()`.